# Twitter typeahead - why does it only match one result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm using the **Twitter Typeahead** plugin:

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '/cgi-bin/admin-daily.cgi',
    remote: {
      url: '/cgi-bin/admin-daily.cgi?q=%QUERY',
      wildcard: '%QUERY',
      filter: function (parsedResponse) {
            console.log(parsedResponse);
            return parsedResponse;
        }
    }
  });

  $('#showSearchResults .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'best-pictures',
    display: 'value',
    source: bestPictures,
    templates: {
      empty: [
        '<div class="empty-message">',
          'unable to find any matches',
        '</div>'
      ].join('\n'),
       suggestion: function(data){
         console.log(data);
         return Mark.up("<img src=\"{{image_url}}\" style=\"height:50px\"> <strong>xx{{title}}yy</strong>", data);
       }
    }
  });

});
```

Now, this kinda works - but it only seem to get 1 result. Here is the JSON that gets returned with my request:

[{"image_url":"https://steampunk-d72.kxcdn.com/daily/7/817-YlMCxegOPpB5Dsob8rw.jpg","title":"Steampunk
 Bike","id":"819"},{"image_url":"https://steampunk-d72.kxcdn.com/daily/1/1041-w0ScJAzItAnL3iFL7Ji1A.jpg"
,"title":"Steampunked Bike","id":"1043"},{"image_url":"https://steampunk-d72.kxcdn.com/daily/4/834-vhJ2bLI9yLdGAbfGetiewA
.jpg","title":"A bike made of spoons by James Rice","id":"836"},{"image_url":"https://steampunk-d72.kxcdn
.com/daily/0/1490-Iqr6FlNjgRgzTRKEYMBq1A.jpg","title":"Bicycle part lamps by ilmecca produzioni ","id"
:"1494"}]

...so as you can see, there are more than one entries, but for some reason it seems to "stop" after the first one:

[image]

At first I thought it was an issue with my code, but I'm not so sure. Maybe someone else can spot whats going on?

Line 34 in the picture above, is:

```
 console.log(data);
```

...within the loop (which is whats confusing me, as it only shows 1 dump - not several, which is what is being returned in the JSON)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why - but its decided to work now!

```
  $('#showSearchResults .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'best-pictures',
    display: 'value',
    source: bestPictures,
    templates: {
      empty: [
        '<div class="empty-message">',
          'unable to find any matches',
        '</div>'
      ].join('\n'),
       suggestion: function(data){
         return Mark.up("<div class=\"view-daily\" rel=\"{{id}}\"><img src=\"{{image_url}}\" style=\"height:50px\"> <strong>{{title}}</strong></div><br>", data);
       }
    }
  });
```

All I really did, was take out the console.log()`call inside the`suggestion:` part - not sure why that would have fixed it, but it seems to have :)